# Skype is causing sound to come from different audio source

Tags: windows, skype, speakers, headphones, spotify

I'm running Spotify for music as well as Skype to chat with a friend, and for the duration of the Skype file transfer start/end sounds audio will play out my speakers if I have headphones plugged in. Is there a way to fix this?

Using an HP Envy 15 with Beats Audio, plugging headphones into the headphone jack on the side of my computer. It didn't do this on my previous laptop (Envy 14, also with Beats Audio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in Skype settings.

Unlike other programs that respect/use the system defaults, Skype has its own audio settings that you must set.

I'm out and about - will update with picture when I get home